# How to draw letters with drawImage (to avoid slow strokeText/fillText)?

Tags: javascript, html, performance, canvas

I found this jsperf, which clearly shows how much faster drawImage is in comparison to fillText:

http://jsperf.com/image-vs-text

But how to actually achieve that if you want your text to be dynamic? It think you need an image with all letters and numbers you need on and then to draw it partially depending on the given string.

Can someone show an example of how that actually works? I read it greatly speeds up your application when you draw text live as rarely as possible...

Comment: If you plan on having a separate image for each glyph and drawing each glyph separately for each character of a string then I'm pretty sure that your script will be slower than `strokeText` and `fillText` __combined__. Why would you want to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Well there is some image to javacript, but the best one i've tried is this plugin for illustrator.

[DrawScript](http://drawscri.pt/)

For example this will generate the code for J:

```
lineStyle="rgb(0,0,0)";
lineWidth=1;
beginPath();
moveTo(223,179);
bezierCurveTo(292,187,361,185,430,192);
bezierCurveTo(474,196,522,203,566,196);
bezierCurveTo(587,192,606,182,627,179);
bezierCurveTo(627,198,611,220,606,238);
bezierCurveTo(595,284,590,330,577,376);
bezierCurveTo(566,419,554,462,542,506);
bezierCurveTo(534,544,530,589,514,625);
bezierCurveTo(487,682,392,696,334,695);
bezierCurveTo(206,689,142,577,179,460);
stroke();
```

It is quiet useful for small letters or something that need to look special. and @font face is not a option